# Program SQL Server 2008R2 to keep retrying a query until all relevant databases are done restoring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

Sometimes our analytics server goes down and I have to use our failover server (I know, I know...). Unfortunately the tables in that server restore every 10 minutes. Is there a way to program SQL to check if a table is being restored and, if so, to periodically retry until it is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687871/database-clients-how-to-wait-for-database-activation-after-sql-server-restart

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Tried searching for this question and I couldn't find it for the life of me!