# Newly entered Data lost in C#.net when server connection has lost on local network

Tags: c#

I am working on a desktop application in C#.net using database SQL 2000 on local network.

Sometimes when user filling the grid with data, the network connection has lost and user dont know about it. when user save the data then error occured and all the data has lost. I used event technique to store the data after each cell value has changed but it takes little time and I want to show the user on screen that Database connection is available or not whenever user click on the form. For that I write a code in click event to check the connection string status. But when I disconnect the network then this code shows that connection is available.

Is there any better way to do all that?

Here is my code

```
private void FrmTMAGazte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DbCon.SQLCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            txtalrt.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            txtalrt.Text = "Connected...";
        }
        else
        {
            txtalrt.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
            txtalrt.Text = "Disconnected";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wondering how if you disconnect the network it shows connection. What do you mean by disconnecting network ?

Comment: how does this cause data loss? you still have the data in the application : just detect a failed save and *reconnect*

Comment: Please split this up into two seperate questions. How to survive a disconnected database connection

Answer (score 0):

Check the code and accepted answer to the following question. It might give you a better solution to what you want to achieve

[In C# what is the best way to determine if a database is up and running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927567/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-database-is-up-and-running?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

From reading your question it looks like that you are resetting/clearing all the entry fields in your form during the save event. You should do that only when you can confirm that data has been saved properly.

You should do something like this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     .... code to save data
     .... code to clear all fields
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     ....error happened, examine the error, if you are not connected try to reconnect but do not clear all fields
     ....this will allow the user to try to save again.
   }
}
```